If $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for every diffrentiable curve $\gamma:[0,1] \to U$, $f \circ \gamma$ is constant a.e. Is $f$ constant a.e.?
Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain (open connected set), and let $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ be a a function such that for every differentiable path $\gamma: [0,1] \to U$ we have that $f \circ \gamma$ is constant almost everywhere. Does it follow that $f$ is constant almost eveywhere? It seems reasonable but I couldn't come up with a proof nor with a counterexample.
I tried to use some sort of Fubini in order to prove it, but I couldn't do it. I thought maybe since on "a very large" (say, uncountable) number of segments one can have even infinitly many points where $f$ is not constant, the results fails. However, I couldn't find a proper counterexample among the Cantor-like known sets.
Can anyone offer any help?

What about $f$? Is it differential a.e. ?

No, assume you don't know that in advance.

I'm far from sure for the validity of this answer I'm giving and I'm asking anyone to correct this, I might be totally wrong. I'm just providing the sloppy idea that came up to mind:
If $f$ is not constant a.e. say for contradiction $f = c_1$ a.e. in $A_1 \subset U$ and $f = c_2$ a.e. in $A_2 \subset U$. Then since U is connected, it is pathwise connected, so there exists a curve (path) $\gamma$ connecting $A_1$ and $A_2$. But $f \circ \gamma$ is constant a.e in $U$ which leads to contradiction.

@mathematico, what did you try in order to solve your problem? Read this thread and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed by moderators because it is a very low-quality question.

@Angelo I edited my question

@mathematico, your post does not have enough context yet, so please read this thread and learn how to ask a good question on this site.
